# make some private members of a class const for some functions

Tags: c++, class, constants

I have a class named `myClass`:

```
myClass
{
    int myFunction1();
    int myFunction2();

private:
int A;
int B;
};
```

In `myFunction1` A should not change but B can be changed.
In `myFunction2` B should not change but A can be changed.

Is there any way to make flexible `const` for each function?
ie `const B` for function1 and vice versa.

Comment: No there is not. Either the function is `const` for all, or not at all.

Comment: Hacks are possible. For example, `class A_t { int A; A_t& operator=(int); public: operator int(); friend int myClass::myFunction1(); };` [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/002a85b453e7baa8)

Comment: Why wont you declare the function arguments as constant passing the A or B as a constant copy to those which shouldn't modify the value? But I agree there is no method of defining members as Flexibly constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not easily possible. You can declare a method `const` which will make all variables `const`. You can declare a member `mutable` so that it can be mutated even in `const` functions. However, you cannot declare a member `mutable` to only some methods.

But the question is: Why would you want that? Simply do not alter `A` in your method. Since the method is in the same file, it should not be too hard to remember that.

If you really need separate encapsulation for `A` and `B` even inside a class, then use an own class for them and move the method to the class, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
private:
   AContainer A;
   BContainer B;
public:
   void myFunction1(){ B.myFynction1(A.get()); }
   void myFunction2(){ A.myFunction2(B.get()); }

   class BContainer {
       int B;
   public:
       int get(){ return B;}
       myFunction1(int A); // May only change B, A is provided as parameter
   }

   class AContainer {
       int A;
   public:
       int get(){ return A;}
       myFunction2(int B); // May only change A, B is provided as parameter
   }

}
```

Comment: I do not want to change it inadvertently.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* need to achieve that behavior you can wrap your `int`s into classes that will befriend specific functions while providing get/set access, like so (very simplified, lacking all the necessary utilities - just to illustrate the point):

```
class TIntA{
public:
    TIntA(int _i) : m_data(_i) {}

    // this function will be able to modify the m_data member but other
    // functions will have to use the get()
    friend int myClass::myFunction1();

    int get() const {return m_data;}

private:
    int m_data;
};
```

I'm sure you can further generalize this approach with templates (can you provide a function as a template parameter? If so you can make this class totally generic)

Comment: *"I'm sure you can further generalize this approach with templates"* It works with classes, but not with functions. You can pass function pointers as non-type template arguments, but not functions themselves.

Comment: Then you can only generalize the type of data stored in it... I think some (ugly?) pre-processor game can be played to provide a template-substitution solution for class declaration. If it is worth it :)

Comment: No, I mean `template<class T> struct foo { friend T; };`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. In that case the class can be fully parametrized for a generic use.